# Getting InvalidToken "The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid" when using GetObjectInput

Tags: go, amazon-s3, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-go

Following the AWS documentation to the letter on how to download an object from S3, I'm getting the `The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid` error.

I'm running my code through the AWS SAM CLI.

My code is:

```
    sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Region: aws.String(endpoints.UsWest2RegionID),
    })

    svc := s3.New(sess)

    aak := os.Getenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY")
    ask := os.Getenv("AWS_SECRET_KEY")
    fmt.Println("aak", aak, "ask", ask) // both of these correctly show my keys are being passed in

    resp, err := svc.GetObject(&s3.GetObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
        Key:    aws.String(key),
    })

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
```

I'm running it with:
`sam local invoke LambdaMyFunction --debug -e test/event.json`

I verified that the AWS Access and Secret keys are correct. I verified that I can download the object through CLI:
`aws s3api get-object --bucket "mybucket-dev" --key "mydir/mykey_test.json" result.txt`

result.txt is populated with the contents of mykey_test.json, so I know my creds have access to the file. I'm assuming the issue has to do with the role that lambda uses not having access to the file? But I can't find enough info to verify that possibility, or how to solve the problem testing locally.

Comment: Try renaming your env vars to `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`

Comment: Just added this: `os.Setenv("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID", aak)` and `os.Setenv("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY", ask)` and did a Getenv on them to make sure they were set. Didn't make any difference.

Comment: Are you putting `Setenv` before `session.NewSession`?

Comment: Yes, but the creds are already passed through from SAM. Which is why I don't have any code actually passing them in (until now). Only code getting and printing them. I did SetEnv just in case SAM was passing them in incorrectly (per your comment above), but that didn't make a difference. I did make sure they are set before the NewSession. I also added `Credentials: credentials.NewEnvCredentials(),` to the config to see if that would make a difference.

Comment: I also printed out `os.Getenv("AWS_REGION")` and it is `us-west-2`. Just curious to see what else is passed through.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out the `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` was being passed in string `(null)`, which is definitely not a valid session token. So my code looks like this:

```
os.Setenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN", "")
sess, _ := session.NewSession()
```

And now I'm able to successfully download the file.

Since we don't yet know how this will be passed in through actual lambda, I set a check on it that looks like this:

```
    // this is STUPID!!! But necessary.
    if os.Getenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN") == "(null)" {
        os.Setenv("AWS_SESSION_TOKEN", "")
    }
    sess, _ := session.NewSession()
```

Comment: Spended days looking for a solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If your SSO,, the, for windows, in a command prompt.. aws sso login --profile  then used sam local invoke 'HelloWorldFunction' --profile  and it works (no Invalid Token error...