# Getting "(InvalidToken) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation" when MLFlow is trying to access the artefacts stored on S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3, mlflow, model-management

I am trying to start the MLFlow server on my local machine inside a python virtual environment using the following command:

```
mlflow server --backend-store-uri postgresql://mlflow_user:mlflow@localhost/mlflow  --artifacts-destination S3://<S3 bucket name>/mlflow/ --serve-artifacts  -h 0.0.0.0 -p 8000
```

I have exported the following environment variables inside the **activated python venv**:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=<access key>
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=<secret key>
export DEFAULT_REGION_NAME=<region name>
export DEFAULT_OUTPUT_FORMAT=<output format>
```

MLFlow gives the following error while accessing the model artefacts for all the runs:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (InvalidToken) when calling the ListObjectsV2 operation: The provided token is malformed or otherwise invalid.
```

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Environment Variables section](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/credentials.html#environment-variables) in the Boto3 official documentation, setting `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` was also necessary.

With reference to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63164723/7422352) added by Stack Overflow user @Francis Lewis, I just reset the AWS access token inside the activated python environment as follows:

```
export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=""
```

And the problem was solved. Thanks to @Francis Lewis!